# Per Process monitoring in C#

Tags: c#, .net, monitoring, monitor

I have been looking for a day to figure out how to do this. I want to monitor the hardware stats of the current process in C#. I figured out how to monitor CPU and memory usage fairly easily using a PerformanceCounter. I would also like to monitor network usage and hard disk usage for the current process.

I know the PerformanceCounter class allows you to monitor overall IO operations for network, hard disk, and devices, but they are bundled together which doesn't help me. I know that PerformanceCounter can track network and disk usage for the entire system and you could compare that before and after certain process operations, but this is not a very good way to monitor your process disk and network usage. Does anyone know how to do this? For the record I am using VS 2012 on a Windows 7 x64 machine.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get that level of granularity for the network traffic.

Comment: @MikyDinescu It must be possible, as `Task Manager`->`Performance`->`Resource Monitor` allows you to see this. In Windows 7.

Comment: Yep, it does for both disk and network access, but for the life of me I can't find any .NET libraries that can. Microsoft obviously created them, but I don't think they allow the public to use them :(

Comment: I don't know nearly enough about it to help you, but it sounds like you can do it with a WMI query.

Comment: I looked into WMI and couldn't find anything, but it is rather large so that isn't to say that it doesn't exist. I appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: wow, interesting there's no way to do this!

Comment: @user99999991 There is, just wasn't obvious perhaps. Look into ETW.